# Detecting which option was selected by the buyer in PayPal IPN Listener

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, html-select

I'm testing my IPN handler with micro-payments using Live PayPal and I want to know how to detect what option was selected when the user clicked my PayPal "Buy Now" button. I've checked many places and found conflicting documentation  and guidance.

Based on another StackOverflow thread, I added the last 4 hidden elements below to the SELECT drop-down OPTION(s) on the ASP.NET page with my Buy Now button:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="hosted_button_id" value="WYUM54ACPKUH6" id="hosted_button_id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="SubType"/>SubType
<select name="os0">
    <option value="S10">Standard (10 users) $0.04 USD</option>
    <option value="ENT">Enterprise (unlimited) $0.05 USD</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="S10"/>
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="ENT"/>
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0.04" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="0.05" />
```

These are not being POSTed back. In a specific test case, I bought the "Standard" option for $0.04 and dumped out the Form variables posted back to my site from PayPal and here are the only things even close to what I am looking for:

```
option_name1 = SubType
option_selection1 = S10
payment_gross = 0.04
```

The threads I read and the doc I read emphasized the naming convention of the OPTION elements and the name and value of the corresponding hidden elements as being as shown above. YET - my testing indicates different things being posted back regarding the choice that was made by the user (i.e. me).

One specific thing is why the suffix is 1 when it seems like it should be 0 (since that first choice and it should be relative to 0). Is there anybody who can clarify what to expect?